# In a Django Model, how can I set values for Django validators based on another field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-validation

I'm trying to track pay in a Djando Model, but this could be annual, daily or hourly, so values for `RangeMinValueValidator` and `RangeMaxValueValidator` should depend on `pay_type`, but I'm not sure how to do this. What I have so far:

```
PAY_TYPE = Choices(
    ('annual', _('Annual')),
    ('daily', _('Daily')),
    ('hourly', _('Hourly')),
)

pay_range = models.IntegerRangeField(
    bounds='[]',
    validators=[
        RangeMinValueValidator(1),
        RangeMaxValueValidator(9999999)
    ]
)
pay_type = models.CharField(choices=PAY_TYPE, default=PAY_TYPE.annual)
```

EDIT:

This feels quite messy, but so far, following Daniel Roseman's comment:

```
def clean(self):
    # Validate pay_range min and max
    annual_pay_range_minimum = 13000
    annual_pay_range_maximum = 9999999
    daily_pay_range_minimum = 25
    daily_pay_range_maximum = 10000
    hourly_pay_range_minimum = 6
    hourly_pay_range_maximum = 500

    if self.pay_type is 'annual':
        pay_range_minimum = annual_pay_range_minimum
        pay_range_maximum = annual_pay_range_maximum
    elif self.pay_type is 'daily':
        pay_range_minimum = daily_pay_range_minimum
        pay_range_maximum = daily_pay_range_maximum
    elif self.pay_type is 'hourly':
        pay_range_minimum = hourly_pay_range_minimum
        pay_range_maximum = hourly_pay_range_maximum
    if (self.pay_range.lower < pay_range_minimum) or (self.pay_range.upper > pay_range_maximum):
        raise ValidationError({
            'pay_range': ValidationError(
                _('%(pay_type)s Pay must be between %(pay_range_minimum)s and %(pay_range_maximum)s'),
                code='invalid',
                params={
                    'pay_type': self.pay_type,
                    'pay_range_minimum': pay_range_minimum,
                    'pay_range_maximum': pay_range_maximum,
                },
            )
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with a field validator. Instead, define the [`clean`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method on the model to check the field values and raise ValidationError if required.

Comment: Thanks, I've put an attempt together in the question, though there has to be a tidier way to do it. Does clean() have to be called in save() if I want it to run on each save?

Comment: I'm calling clean() in a pre_save method.